# Mongoose Filter an array ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, objectid

I have a document that has a array of ObjectIDs for reference.Like below

```
{
  ...courseTypes: {
    type: [{
      type: app.db.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'CourseType'
    }],
    default: []
  },
  ...
}
```

So now i want to get all data that courseTypes contain a ObjectId (let say _id) but i don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: please add sample input and expected output and also `CourseType` schema

Comment: and check [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)